# Nice inequality ,Prove that $\Gamma\Big(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Big)\leq \frac{\pi}{\pi-x}$

Tags: limits, inequality, gamma-function, pi

Playing with geogebra I get :

> > Let $0\leq x<\pi$ then we have :
> > $$\Gamma\Big(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Big)\leq \frac{\pi}{\pi-x}$$
> > Where we have the Gamma function .

I have tried to use the [Wendel inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality) to prove that the ratio of the LHS and the RHS is one when $x$ tends to $\pi$ without success . The derivative is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20gamma%28sin%28x%29%2Fx%29-pi%2F%28pi-x%29) but I can't handle it . I have tried power series of the Gamma function but I think it's reveals nothing good . So now I think it's not a trivial problem and I can't solve it .

My question :

How to solve it properly ?

Thanks in advance for your comments\answers.

Comment: Writing $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$ may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over $[0,\pi]$
$$ \Gamma\left(1+\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) \leq 1 \leq \frac{\pi \sin(x)}{x(\pi -x)}.$$

Comment: That's really great ! I can conlude since $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x}=\Gamma(x)$. Thanks you! I would like to upvote twice .

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know how much this could help you.*

Since you played with Geogebra, you could check that the function
$$f(x)=\Gamma\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)-\frac{\pi}{\pi-x}$$ can be quite nicely *approximated* by its $[1,1]$ Padé approximant built around $x=\frac \pi 2$
$$f(x) \sim \frac {a_0+a_1\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2} \right)} {1+a_2\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2} \right)}$$  The coefficients are quite nasty (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PadeApproximant%5B-%28Pi%2F%28Pi+-+x%29%29+%2B+Gamma%5BSin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%5D%2C%7Bx%2CPi%2F2%2C%7B1%2C1%7D%7D%5D)) but numerically, they are
$$a_0 =-0.589172 \qquad a_1=-0.36822\qquad a_2=-0.164027$$

The maximum absolute error is $0.0086$ at $x=0$.

On the other hand, we also have
$$f(x)=-\frac{x}{\pi }+\left(\frac{\gamma }{6}-\frac{1}{\pi ^2}\right)
   x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$f(x)=(-1-\gamma )+\left(-\frac{\gamma ^2}{2 \pi }-\frac{\pi }{4}\right) (x-\pi
   )+\frac{(x-\pi )^2 \left(6 \gamma ^2-2 \gamma ^3-\pi ^2-\gamma  \pi ^2+2 \psi
   ^{(2)}(1)\right)}{12 \pi ^2}+O\left((x-\pi )^3\right)$$